# Solution verification: If $m(E)>0$, then there exists $x\in E$ such that $m(E\cap B(x,\delta))>0, \forall \delta>0$.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Let $E\subset \mathbb{R}^d$ be Lebesgue measurable such that $m(E)>0$. ($m$ is Lebesgue measure.) Show that there exists $x\in E$ such that $m(E\cap B(x,\delta))>0$, for all $\delta>0$. $B(x,\delta)$ denotes the ball of radius $\delta$ centered at $x$.

My solution: All integrals are over $\mathbb{R}^d$

$$\int m(E\cap B(x,\delta))dx=\int\int \chi_{E\cap B(x,\delta)}(t)\; dtdx = \int\int \chi_E(x) \cdot \chi_{B(x,\delta)}(t)\; dtdx=m(E)\cdot m(B(x,\delta))>0$$

Since $\int m(E\cap B(x,\delta))dx>0,$ there exists $x\in E$ such that $m(E\cap B(x,\delta))>0, \forall\delta>0$.

Question: Is this correct? If not, can it be fixed so that the main idea of the solution still applies? Thanks.

P.S. I know this problem has been asked here before but I'm specifically looking for feedback on my solution.

Comment: this can't be right, because you're starting with an integral over $x$, but in the end your answer depends on $x$.

Comment: Thank you. Is there anything I can use from this solution? Can it be corrected?

Comment: Lebesgue's differentiation theorem tells us that for a.e $x\in\Bbb{R}^n$, $\lim\limits_{\delta\to 0^+}\frac{m(E\cap B(x,\delta))}{m(B(x,\delta))}=\mathbf{1}_E(x)$. So, for a.e $x\in E$, the numerator is positive. This might be overkill, but it's efficient.